# Changing from Sendmail to Codeigniter Email class

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter, email

Im currently developing a codeigniter website which sending emails from contact form.till this time i used the sendmail library by the Xampp and the mail sended successfully.

The flow mail sending in my project is follows:

Contact form >> on clicking Send button it goes to a javascript code which validating the inputs >> an ajax that call my_email.php which is a normal php code for sending mail (my_email.php placed inside application/view and put corresponding controller code on my controller).

```
 $send = @mail($global_email, $subject, $message, $headers);  // normal php code for sending mail
```

so the website is now using the sendmail(sendmail.ini) libary by Xampp. but when i hosting this website it do not support sendmail anymore, it supports only the **email** class on codeigniter which is located in **system/library/email.php** as per my codeigniter.

currently there is no email.php file isnide **application/cofig**.

So my question is that, (1) what will be the content of that **system/library/email.php** without changing any content from my_email.php .?
(2) how i load this **system/library/email.php** class to my website.?

Answer (score 0):

You can read about the email class of codeigniter here: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/email.html

In general the usage is like the following:

```
//load the email class as a library
$this->load->library('email');

$this->email->from('your@example.com', 'Your Name');
$this->email->to('someone@example.com'); 
$this->email->cc('another@another-example.com'); 
$this->email->bcc('them@their-example.com'); 

$this->email->subject('Email Test');
$this->email->message('Testing the email class.');  

$this->email->send();
```

You just need to change you code appropriately where you are using the mail() function in your controllers/models to use the Email Class of codeigniter. If you are using ajax to send your email you should make a controller that handles the ajax request from your website and point to that from your javascript function that does the form validation/handling.